# how to format jquery ui datepicker with no theme

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a datepicker such that it has no jquery ui theme. It appears quite plain but that doesn't matter for me.

However, it doesn't have current date sign, and previous-next months arrows (However, next-previous month functions work when I click the top corners of the patepicker).

I don't want to use any jquery ui theme, because I have my own css file for dialog, and I managed to make my custom dialog box appearance, and I don't want to ruin it.

How can I make show it just current date sign and prev-next months arrows?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't strip the needed css for your datepicker and use the code as the base and leave the rest from jQuery-ui out of it.

For example make a new css file jquery-ui-datepicker.css or merge it somewhere else in your code.
You can adjust the CSS for your needs for example altering colors and margins.

Don't forget to include a icon image from the jQuery ui for the next and prev buttons.
On the http://jqueryui.com/download/ you can select your download package for selecting only the datepicker module.